# How to retrieve DATE values from VARCHAR2 column. VARCHAR 2 column is a combination of numbers, characters, decimal and dates

Tags: sql, oracle

How to retrieve only DATE values(MM/DD/YYYY) from VARCHAR2 column. VARCHAR2 column is a combination of numbers, characters, decimal and dates.

Varchar2 column values like below:

```
Unity rrr
Project
12/31/2019
actyu
12/31/2018
12/31/2017
109.83
12/31/2016
2021
1111
```

I have tried with SUBSTR, REGEXP_REPLACE but no luck.

Comment: You state that the dates are in format DD/MM/YYYY but in your example you show 12/31/2019. Which one is it?

Comment: Does your example regard the column value of a single row? I.e., the value may contain multiple dates?

Comment: yeah, MM/DD/YYYY is right one, sorry for wrong date. column value is not a single row, its multiple rows. Below are the 11 rows for varchar2 column.

Unity, 
rrr, 
Project, 
12/31/2019, 
actyu, 
12/31/2018, 
12/31/2017, 
109.83, 
12/31/2016, 
2021, 
1111.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if something like this helps.

Sample data:

```
SQL> WITH
  2     test (col)
  3     AS
  4        (SELECT 'Unity rrr' FROM DUAL
  5         UNION ALL
  6         SELECT 'Project' FROM DUAL
  7         UNION ALL
  8         SELECT '12/31/2019' FROM DUAL
  9         UNION ALL
 10         SELECT 'actyu' FROM DUAL
 11         UNION ALL
 12         SELECT '12/31/2018' FROM DUAL
 13         UNION ALL
 14         SELECT '12/31/2017' FROM DUAL
 15         UNION ALL
 16         SELECT '109.83' FROM DUAL
 17         UNION ALL
 18         SELECT '12/31/2016' FROM DUAL
 19         UNION ALL
 20         SELECT '2021' FROM DUAL
 21         UNION ALL
 22         SELECT '1111' FROM DUAL)
```

`TO_DATE` will return

- `SYSDATE` by default if there's an error and
- `DATE` datatype value if `COL` is a valid date value

for all rows whose `COL` contains [2 digits + 2 digits + 4 digits] separated by a slash.

```
 23  SELECT col, TO_DATE (col DEFAULT SYSDATE ON CONVERSION ERROR, 'mm/dd/yyyy') result
 24    FROM test
 25   WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (col, '^\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}$');

COL        RESULT
---------- ----------
12/31/2019 12/31/2019
12/31/2018 12/31/2018
12/31/2017 12/31/2017
12/31/2016 12/31/2016

SQL>
```

Comment: This will return invalid rows such as `02/29/2001`, `99/99/9999` or `00/00/0000`.

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle 12, to convert the string you can use `TO_DATE(value DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR, format_model)` with the format model `FXMM/DD/YYYY` (if you don't do an exact match with the `FX` format model then you may find unexpected matches, see the last line of the sample output below).

```sql
SELECT value,
       TO_DATE(
         value DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR,
         'FXMM/DD/YYYY'
       ) As dt,
       TO_DATE(
         value DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR,
         'MM/DD/YYYY'
       ) As non_exact_format
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
SELECT 'Unity rrr' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Project' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '12/31/2019' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'actyu' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '12/31/2018' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '12/31/2017' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '109.83' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '12/31/2016' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2021' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '02/29/2001' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '99/99/9999' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '00/00/0000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '11111111' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| VALUE | DT | NON_EXACT_FORMAT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Unity rrr | *null* | *null* |
| Project | *null* | *null* |
| 12/31/2019 | 2019-12-31 00:00:00 | 2019-12-31 00:00:00 |
| actyu | *null* | *null* |
| 12/31/2018 | 2018-12-31 00:00:00 | 2018-12-31 00:00:00 |
| 12/31/2017 | 2017-12-31 00:00:00 | 2017-12-31 00:00:00 |
| 109.83 | *null* | *null* |
| 12/31/2016 | 2016-12-31 00:00:00 | 2016-12-31 00:00:00 |
| 2021 | *null* | *null* |
| 02/29/2001 | *null* | *null* |
| 99/99/9999 | *null* | *null* |
| 00/00/0000 | *null* | *null* |
| 11111111 | *null* | 1111-11-11 00:00:00 |

---

If you only want the valid dates then you can also filter the rows using `VALIDATE_CONVERSION`:

```sql
SELECT value,
       TO_DATE(
         value DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR,
         'FXMM/DD/YYYY'
       ) As dt
FROM   table_name
WHERE  VALIDATE_CONVERSION(value AS DATE, 'FXMM/DD/YYYY') = 1;
```

Which, for the sample data, outputs:

| VALUE | DT |
| --- | --- |
| 12/31/2019 | 2019-12-31 00:00:00 |
| 12/31/2018 | 2018-12-31 00:00:00 |
| 12/31/2017 | 2017-12-31 00:00:00 |
| 12/31/2016 | 2016-12-31 00:00:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9V7nvKEd)